# Hooking two washing machines up to one hot/cold water supply

Tags: plumbing

I need a new washing machine and am leaning towards getting a stackable front loader (soon to be family of 6; it's just more efficient water/energy-wise), however, I also plan to cloth diaper my baby and know front loaders suck for washing diapers. I have a small apartment sized washer/dryer that I could use for the diapers but can't afford the new washer AND getting my laundry room plumbed with a second water supply. Is it possible to install some kind of valve that would allow me to switch between one laundry pair and the other? I realize I wouldn't be able to run them both at the same time (or would I...?) If I put two washer/dryers in my laundry room I wouldn't have room to just disconnect/reconnect the supplies, but I could probably get a hand back there to manipulate a valve...

Let's assume for now draining is not an issue...

Comment: You don't need to switch the water supply between machines. You can have them both connected and turned on at the same time. - They will interfere with each other only if you run both at the same time, and even then all that will happen is that they may both take a little longer to fill.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a hose wye with shut-offs on both hot and cold. Make sure you buy a heavy duty brass one with ball valves. You **can** run both washers simultaneously as they fill until a sensor or float says the water level has risen to the set-point. It will just take a bit longer for them to fill if you run them at the same time.

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, you can leave all four of the ball valves open all the time. You need close them only when removing one of the washers.